# TextAnnotation blocktype shows only text

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am trying to use the DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION. But, even when the input files contain only images, the `blocktype` property in the JSON output **never** gives the value `PICTURE`. It only gives `TEXT`.

Comment: why you think you should receive picture tag?

Comment: If blocktype is always text, why would it be there?
I checked the possible values and they include text, figure, title, barcode, among other things.

Comment: You right that this options exist, maybe the  DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION limits it to be just text, I cant find documentation for it but maybe it worth to investigate it